# Lightning Chart JS Blurry on Mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, lightningchart

I am working on getting a basic LightningChart example up and running in electron, looking to write a cross-platform charting app for my industry.

I grabbed the demo HTML code from the website and plopped it into my app, here's how it looks.

[image: Blurry LightningChart JS image from Mac OS]

As you can see the text is quite pixelated. Is this a Mac thing? Is it a chart setting?

It's not *as* bad in Windows:

[image: Windows Screenshot of the Same App]

Here's the code in my lightning.js source file.

```
// Replace the contents of this script tag if you want to test code from our examples:
// https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/

// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
    lightningChart
} = lcjs //Note: @arction/lcjs is not needed here, when using IIFE assembly

// Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    // Set the chart into a div with id, 'target'. 
    // Chart's size will automatically adjust to div's size. 
    container: 'target'
})
    .setTitle('My first chart') // Set chart title

const data = [
    { x: 0, y: 1.52 },
    { x: 1, y: 1.56 },
    { x: 2, y: 1.42 },
    { x: 3, y: 1.85 },
    { x: 4, y: 1.62 }
]

// Add a line series.
const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries()
    .setName('My data')
    .add(data)
```

Literally taken right from their website.

It's inserted into this tag in the HTML

```
    <!-- Create div to render the chart into-->
    <div id="target" class="row content"></div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whelp, I figured it out, had to add this to the  tag to enable support for high DPI devices. Jees!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```